# jQuery ui - droppable inside droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using droppable inside droppable, but child droppable not working.

**What I am tryin to do**

- I have a parent droppable `#droppable`.
- My first parent droppable accepts two elements `#child-drop1` and `#child-drop2`.
- Again i want above two elements `#child-drop1` and `#child-drop2` to behave as droppable wrapper.
- but now when I want to drop elements in child droppable noting happens.
- that's all.

---

```
   jQuery( '#droppable' ).droppable({
        activeClass: 'active',
        accept:'#child-drop1, #child-drop2',
        hoverClass: 'hover',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            jQuery('<div id="child-drop"><div>).appendTo( this );
        }
    }); 

    jQuery( '#child-drop1, #child-drop2' ).droppable({
        activeClass: 'active',
        accept:'#child-child-drop',
        hoverClass: 'hover',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            jQuery('<div id="child-child-drop"><div>').appendTo( this );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add HTML also in OP

Comment: We have put a droppable in your droppable, so you can drop while you're dropping.

Answer (score 0):

I have added below code and HTML & CSS for demo and its working fine [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6z8Ax/)

```
jQuery('#child-drop1, #child-drop2, #child-child-drop').draggable({revert: 'invalid'});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, in OP you said "but now when I want to drop elements in child droppable noting happens.:" but in jsFiddle child droppable accepting dropped element `#child-child-drop`